# Unable to install some programs due to CD/DVD prompt

Tags: installation

when I tried to install firestarter and the gnome shell, i get the following error:

> CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release amd64
>   (20120823.1)' is required
>
> Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/cdrom/' to install
>   software packages from it.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either insert your DVD

else

remove cdrom as software source

To do that go to **Ubuntu Software Center** --> **Edit** menu --> choose **software sources** then uncheck the **option installable from CD**

[image]